# When you call a java standalone application from an eclipse workbench inside a plugin, this indicates interprocess communication?

Tags: java, eclipse, interprocess

The fact that from an eclipse plugin i invoke a swing java application from my own library we can say that this is interprocess communication since eclipse is by itself a java application running on top of a jvm and then i load into the jvm another process passing some arguments from the initial plugin workbench

Comment: Is this a question about terminology, or about how to do such communication?

Answer (score 0):

I think simply *passing command line arguments* would normally not be called interprocess communication, though it is a really weak form of it.

Usually you would want to have at least some data passing while the programs are running, and usually in both directions. In Java, this could be done by reading the standard input/outputstreams, using Sockets (or anything based on this, like RMI), or using a shared file (Try [mapping the file into memory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) as a ByteBuffer from both processes - though it seems to be system-dependent whether other processes see the changes). Or using system-dependent methods per JNI.